# InvalidOperationException: list but should be a vm value

Tags: c#

Error message:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Howest.Grade.Web.ViewModels.ProjectsDetailVm]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'Howest.Grade.Web.ViewModels.ProjectsDetailVm'.

Controller

```
using Howest.Grade.Web.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Howest.Grade.Web.Controllers
{
    public class ProjectsController : Controller
    {
        private GradeContext _gradeContext;

        public ProjectsController(GradeContext gradeContext)
        {
            _gradeContext = gradeContext;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Route("Detail/{ProjectId?}")]
        public IActionResult Detail(Guid? ProjectId)
        {

            if (ProjectId == null)
            {
                return NotFound("ProjectId not found");
            }

            var projectsDetailVm = _gradeContext.Projects
                .Where(m => m.Id == ProjectId)
                .Select(project => new ProjectsDetailVm
                {
                    ProjectId = project.Id,
                    Name = project.Name,
                    CreationDate = project.CreationDate,
                    CreatedByUserId = project.CreatedByUserId,
                    Description = project.Description,
                    CompanyId = project.Company.Id,
                    CompanyName = project.Company.Name,
                    DeletionDate = project.DeletionDate,
                    DeletedByUserId = project.DeletedByUserId,
                    UpdateDate = project.UpdateDate,
                    UpdatedByUserId = project.UpdatedByUserId,
                    IsDeleted = project.IsDeleted
                }).ToList();

            if(projectsDetailVm == null)
            {
                return NotFound("Project not found");
            }

            return View(projectsDetailVm);
        }
    }
}
```

View model:

```
using CoreLibrary.Lib;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Howest.Grade.Web.ViewModels
{
    public class ProjectsDetailVm
    {
        public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public Guid? CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DeletionDate { get; set; }
        public Guid? DeletedByUserId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }
        public Guid? UpdatedByUserId { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public Guid? ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
        public Guid? ProjectStatusId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
    @model Howest.Grade.Web.ViewModels.ProjectsDetailVm

    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Detail";
    }

    <h1>Detailpagina</h1>


    <h4>Project: @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Name)</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            Project nummer:
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProjectId)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            Beschrijving
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            Bedrijfsnaam
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CompanyName)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            Aanmaak datum
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CreationDate)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            Gebruiker dat het project aangemaakt heeft
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CreatedByUserId)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            Datum van verwijderen
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DeletionDate)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            Gebruiker dat het project verwijderd heeft
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DeletedByUserId)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            Datum van update
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UpdateDate)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            Gebruiker dat het project geupdated heeft
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UpdatedByUserId)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            Is het verwijderd?
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.IsDeleted)
        </dd>
    </dl>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.ProjectId">Aanpassen</a> |
        <a asp-action="Index">Terug</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help to see your `cshtml` view, but this error is usually caused (in my experience) by a mismatch between the type returned from the controller and the `@model` in the view. So in your view, you probably have:

`@model ProjectsDetailVm`

But it should be:

`@model IEnumerable<ProjectsDetailVm>`

**UPDATE**

If you only want one `ProjectsDetailVm`, you should add a `.SingleOrDefault()` to your LINQ query to ensure that only one object is returned:

```c#
var projectsDetailVm = _gradeContext.Projects
    .Where(m => m.Id == ProjectId)
    .Select(project => new ProjectsDetailVm
    {
        ProjectId = project.Id,
        Name = project.Name,
        CreationDate = project.CreationDate,
        CreatedByUserId = project.CreatedByUserId,
        Description = project.Description,
        CompanyId = project.Company.Id,
        CompanyName = project.Company.Name,
        DeletionDate = project.DeletionDate,
        DeletedByUserId = project.DeletedByUserId,
        UpdateDate = project.UpdateDate,
        UpdatedByUserId = project.UpdatedByUserId,
        IsDeleted = project.IsDeleted
    }).SingleOrDefault();
```

As it stands currently, your `if(projectsDetailVm == null)` will never be `true` because if there are no rows then `projectsDetailVm` will be an empty collection and not `null`. I assume you only expect one `ProjectsDetailVm` because of `Where(m => m.Id == ProjectId)`.